# How to use multiline properties in property file in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Currently working on **Selenium WebDriver** and code had been written in **Java**.

In the below code i can able to check the dropdown values is matching with the UI. But i tried for only one drop down. The same method i want to check for many drop down options one by one.

In this code the property file contains the drop down as **visualizationId=Day,Week,Month,Quarter,Semester,Year,RD Tech Group,ICC,Center,Software Pack,Product,Project,Customer PRs,Severity,Priority**

It is checking properly and the same options is available in UI or not.

If i had many like **visualizationId=Day,Week,Month,Quarter,Semester,Year,RD Tech Group,ICC,Center,Software Pack,Product,Project,Customer PRs,Severity,Priority**

**periodId=Last 4 Weeks,Last 52 Weeks,Date Range,Week Range,Month Range,Year To Date**

How can i perform this

The Code is:

```
@Test()
public void Filterselection_1() throws Exception{

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\FilterSection\\visualization.txt"));
String line;
line = in.readLine();
in.close();

String[] expectedDropDownItemsInArray = line.split("=")[1].split(",");

// Create expected list :: This will contain expected drop-down values
ArrayList<String> expectedDropDownItems = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<expectedDropDownItemsInArray.length; i++)
    expectedDropDownItems.add(expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i]);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('visualizationId').style.display='block';");

// Create a webelement for the drop-down
WebElement visualizationDropDownElement = driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId"));

// Instantiate Select class with the drop-down webelement
Select visualizationDropDown = new Select(visualizationDropDownElement);

// Retrieve all drop-down values and store in actual list
List<WebElement> valuesUnderVisualizationDropDown  = visualizationDropDown.getOptions();

List<String> actualDropDownItems = new ArrayList<String>();

for(WebElement value : valuesUnderVisualizationDropDown){
    actualDropDownItems.add(value.getText());
}

// Print expected and actual list
System.out.println("expectedDropDownItems : " +expectedDropDownItems);       
System.out.println("actualDropDownItems : " +actualDropDownItems);

// Verify both the lists having same size
if(actualDropDownItems.size() != expectedDropDownItems.size())
  System.out.println("Property file is NOT updated with the drop-down values");

// Compare expected and actual list
for (int i = 0; i < actualDropDownItems.size(); i++) {
    if (!expectedDropDownItems.get(i).equals(actualDropDownItems.get(i)))
    System.out.println("Drop-down values are NOT in correct order");

}
```

String[] expectedDropDownItemsInArray1 = line.split("=")[1].split(",");

```
// Create expected list :: This will contain expected drop-down values

ArrayList<String> expectedDropDownItems1 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<expectedDropDownItemsInArray1.length; i++)
    expectedDropDownItems1.add(expectedDropDownItemsInArray1[i]);// Same VisualizationId values it is taking but it need to take 2nd i.e PeriodId drop down and it need to check

JavascriptExecutor executor1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor1.executeScript("document.getElementById('periodId').style.display='block';");

// Create a webelement for the drop-down
WebElement periodDropDownElement = driver.findElement(By.id("periodId"));

// Instantiate Select class with the drop-down webelement
Select periodDropDown = new Select(periodDropDownElement);

// Retrieve all drop-down values and store in actual list
List<WebElement> valuesUnderPeriodDropDown  = periodDropDown.getOptions();

List<String> actualDropDownItems1 = new ArrayList<String>();

for(WebElement value : valuesUnderPeriodDropDown){
    actualDropDownItems1.add(value.getText());
}

// Print expected and actual list
System.out.println("expectedDropDownItems : " +expectedDropDownItems1);       
System.out.println("actualDropDownItems : " +actualDropDownItems1);

// Verify both the lists having same size
if(actualDropDownItems1.size() != expectedDropDownItems1.size())
  System.out.println("Property file is NOT updated with the drop-down values");

// Compare expected and actual list
for (int i = 0; i < actualDropDownItems1.size(); i++) {
    if (!expectedDropDownItems1.get(i).equals(actualDropDownItems1.get(i)))
    System.out.println("Drop-down values are NOT in correct order");

}
```

}

Comment: Can anyone suggest me the solution

Comment: Re use the above method for all the properties by passing the property value as a parameter.

Comment: Is this a **.properties** file or **.txt** file?

Comment: @mfsi_sitamj it is a .txt file

Comment: could you pls help me how to tackle

Comment: Better to use a property file. Can we?

Comment: ok let me know that as well.. And please check for the txt file

Comment: That .properties file will be in c directory or in eclipse

Comment: Place the properties file in the same location as the txt file.

Comment: let me know how to call each and every options visualizationId=Day,Week,Month,Quarter,Semester,Year,RD Tech Group,ICC,Center,Software Pack,Product,Project,Customer PRs,Severity,Priority
periodId=Last 4 Weeks,Last 52 Weeks,Date Range,Week Range,Month Range,Year To Date

Comment: 1st visualization then period id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

visualization.properties file will look like the following:

[image: visualization.properties]

Properties file contains basically two things : **property name** and **property value**
In *visualization.properties* file, **visualizationId** and **periodId** are **property name** and corresponding **property values** are assigned using **=** operator.

Updated your posted code to read expected drop-down values from visualization.properties file:

```
public void Filterselection_1() throws Exception{

Properties APPTEXT = new Properties();
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("C:\\FilterSection\\visualization.properties");
APPTEXT.load(fs);
String[] expectedDropDownItemsInArray = APPTEXT.getProperty("visualizationId").trim().split(",");

// Create expected list :: This will contain expected drop-down values
ArrayList<String> expectedDropDownItems = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<expectedDropDownItemsInArray.length; i++)
    expectedDropDownItems.add(expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i]);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('visualizationId').style.display='block';");

// Create a webelement for the drop-down
WebElement visualizationDropDownElement = driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId"));

// Instantiate Select class with the drop-down webelement
Select visualizationDropDown = new Select(visualizationDropDownElement);

// Retrieve all drop-down values and store in actual list
List<WebElement> valuesUnderVisualizationDropDown  = visualizationDropDown.getOptions();

List<String> actualDropDownItems = new ArrayList<String>();

for(WebElement value : valuesUnderVisualizationDropDown){
    actualDropDownItems.add(value.getText());
}

// Print expected and actual list
System.out.println("expectedDropDownItems : " +expectedDropDownItems);       
System.out.println("actualDropDownItems : " +actualDropDownItems);

// Verify both the lists having same size
if(actualDropDownItems.size() != expectedDropDownItems.size())
  System.out.println("Property file is NOT updated with the drop-down values");

// Compare expected and actual list
for (int i = 0; i < actualDropDownItems.size(); i++) {
    if (!expectedDropDownItems.get(i).equals(actualDropDownItems.get(i)))
    System.out.println("Drop-down values are NOT in correct order");

}
```

**Note :** 
`APPTEXT.getProperty("visualizationId")` will return **Day,Week,Month,Quarter,Semester,Year,RD Tech Group,ICC,Center,Software Pack,Product,Project,Customer PRs,Severity,Priority** value.

In order to get value corresponding to **periodId** use - `APPTEXT.getProperty("periodId")`

Comment: How the .properties will looks like. once it executed then how can i check for Periodid that values also should present in same property file .properties

Comment: my problem is about selecting options one by one why need to change as a .properties. In .txt it seems the visualization is worked fine

Comment: See my updated answer! Basically you have to use `APPTEXT.getProperty("visualizationId")` and `APPTEXT.getProperty("periodId")` to get values corresponding to **visualizationId** and **periodId**

Comment: In this can i want to add one more scenario. In Period drop down if i select month Range then i need to verify the exact month range drop down need to populate. Please go through the link and help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776164/how-to-verify-the-drop-down-belongs-to-another-drop-down-in-selenium-webdriver#